# Obtener el DataSource de una conexion sql mediante codigo en c#

Tags: c#

Vengo aquí nuevamente con la intención de recibir su ayuda a una duda que mantengo tengo en el siguiente código que me realiza el backup de una base de datos cuando es pulsado en un boton, la pregunta consiste en si se puede obtener el datasource de la instancia de la base de datos mediante código y no manualmente como se visualiza aquí tengo el código.

```
public void Generar_Backup()
    {
        try
        {
            Crear_Carpeta_Backup();
            Borrar_Carpeta_Backup(@"d:\Backup", deleteThis: false);
            var backup = new Backup();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI; Data Source=LAPTOPCLIEQU\SQLEXPRESS");-- AQUI LO AÑADO MANUALMENTE.
            var sc = new ServerConnection(con);
            Server server = new Server(sc);
            backup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
            backup.Database = "DIENTES_SANOS";
            backup.Devices.AddDevice(@"d:\Backup\Backups.bak", DeviceType.File);
            backup.BackupSetName = "DIENTESSANOSDB";
            backup.Initialize = false;
            backup.PercentComplete += CompletionStatusInPercent;
            backup.Complete += Backup_Completed;
            backup.SqlBackup(server);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR:" + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola, me puedes decir si la respuesta dada te fue util,gracias

Comment: Hola, que tal basicamente esa parte ya la habia realizado lo que buscaba o deseaba era saber si mediante codigo se podria obtener de manera automatica el nombre del servidor sin necesidad de hacer la configuracion de la app.config.

Answer (score 0):

Cada proyecto hecho en .Net tiene un fichero de configuracion llamado **App.Config** para las aplicaciones de escritorio o **Web.Config**, para aplicaciones web.

**App.config** es un archivo **XML** compuesto por varias secciones de configuración predefinidas y ademas permite incorporar secciones de configuracion personalizadas. Una sección de configuración almacena información, como por ejemplo la cadena de conexion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dado que este fichero tiene lo que buscas pues puedes utilizarlo para obtener dicha cadena de conexion.

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyKey"].ConnectionString;
```

Con este codigo obtenemos la cadena de conexion que se guarda en el fichero **App.Config**.

"MyKey" viene siendo el nombre de la seccion a la que vamos a acceder. Fijate en la imagen de abajo como el atributo name tiene como valor a "MyKey". Tu fichero tendra otro nombre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para poder ejecutar este codigo debes incluir la referencia

```
System.Configuration.dll
```

Para ello hacemos los siguiente:

En el explorador de soluciones del proyecto damos clic derecho en **References** y seleccionamos la opcion **Add Reference...**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la ventana que nos sale buscamos la dll **System.Configuration** y la añadimos.

Por ultimo añadimos en los usings:

```
using System.Configuration;
```